# Calling a functional component's method from separate third-party component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a stateless functional component `ReceivingComponent` that uses a third-party dependency that has a method I want to call when an event from a separate component `TransmittingComponent` is fired.

In my example I have a Map component that contains a `MapBox` instance and I'm trying to fire the resize method when it receives an event from a separate component that has a `onDrag` event.

Most solutions to this problem involve using `refs` to access a components methods, but as I'm using functional component I can't use `refs` so I'm exploring other solutions.

I've hacked together something with Redux where I'm setting a boolean value in a store to `true`, Then inside the `ReceivingComponent` I have a useEffect that when boolean is `true` the `doThing` method is called. The boolean value in the store is then reset to `false`. It works, but makes my skin crawl.

```
<ParentComponent>
  <ReceivingComponent doThing={}/>
  <TransmittingComponent onEvent={} />
</ParentComponent>
```

In other frameworks I might create an event bus, that emits an event when `TransmittingComponent` fires its event. And then inside `ReceivingComponent` I listen for that event to then trigger the method required. But I can't find a method of doing that with React or Redux.

Is there a way with React / Redux to be able to access a components methods from another component without using `Refs`. Or even emit a global event and listen for that event from another component?

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to accomplish this in case you have control over the ReceivingComponent is to pass the TransmittingComponent as a child.

```
 <ReceivingComponent>
    {({doThing}) => <TransmittingComponent onClick={doThing} />}
 </ReceivingComponent>
```

Here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-worker-6my9h)

But if these components are siblings for a reason, another option that comes to my mind is to use some piece of state in the ParentComponent to notify ReceivingComponent that the event was fired.

Here is another [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-grass-pdery)

I suppose it's somewhat similar to what you made with Redux.
It may look not so sexy, but I saw this pattern also in FRP, to convert DOM events somehow into streams.